# How to avoid killing my best buddy?

Tags: far-cry-2

My first and very bestest buddy Josip is, well... *a few bullets short of a full clip*. His crazy, hare-brained schemes have gotten us both in a spot of bother quite a few times.

For example, his definition of 'ambush' seems to be:

> Stand in the middle of the road and shoot a shotgun at an oncoming jeep, fitted with a .50 Cal machine gun and a trigger happy Australian/South African manning it. (The accent sounds Australian anyway. Well, American-Australian)

Needless to say he's been downed quite a few times, and I've had to revive him. A couple of times he didn't make it, and I had to reload and try again (I like to keep my buddies if I can). But this latest one, no matter how many times I reload I can't revive him. *(I reload to a save before he even gets downed I might add, but it seems almost impossible for him NOT to be downed by the time I get to him)*

Which leads me to believe there is an upper-limit on the amount of times you can revive a buddy. Or at the very least a lower and lower chance of a successful revive each time you perform a revive (limit→ 0).

Is this the case? or have I just had a really bad run with revives lately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Far Cry wiki](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Buddy), as well as personal experience:

**Buddies have only 3 lives.  During the fourth attempt to revive them, the player can only mercy kill them (either via syrette overdose or gunshot).**

If you want Josep to live, you may need to restart the mission or reload from a save further back.  Long-term, you may want to start thinking about getting a new best buddy.